# How to use JQuery on a WordPress Page/Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

this has been annoying me for several hours now.

So I have a WordPress page which a html form. I'm currently trying to do two things with this form. A) Get a JQuery plugin to work which converts the select form into a multiple select checkbox style form. B) Retain all the information after it has been submitted.

Currently I use a plugin called Chosen which kind of does A for me, but it doesn't act as a checkbox and as far as I know, doesn't allow me to retain information after the post.

```
multiple="multiple" name="other_qualifications[]">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="Personnel Management Training">Personnel Management Training</option>
<option value="WH&amp;S">WH&amp;S [Workplace Health &amp; Safety] Training</option>
<option value="First Aid Training">First Aid Training</option>
<option value="Barista Training">Barista Training</option>
<option value="RSA">RSA [Responsible Service of Alcohol] Training</option>
<option value="Specialised Culinary Training">Specialised Culinary Training</option>
<option value="Front-of-House Training">Front-of-House Training</option>
<option value="Back-of-House Training">Back-of-House Training</option>
<option value="Wait-staff Training">Wait-staff Training</option>
<option value="House-keeping Training">Hotel &amp; House-keeping Training</option>
</select>
```

Anyway, long story short I want to use either http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ or http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/

I've followed guides on adding things to the functions.php file but I've had no luck.

For part 3 in the first link above for example, I'm not sure if that code is meant to go on the same page as the form, or somewhere else.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite stuck right now.

Cheers.

Comment: "I've followed guides on adding things to the functions.php file but I've had no luck." Can you show us the code you've added to the file, to see if you've done it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a page template for this purpose, or simply embed all necessary code inside the page content

WordPress simply includes the page's content converted to HTML at the place in your template file where `the_content()` is called. This means you could theoretically include any HTML, CSS or JS that you want to render on the page inside the HTML view of your post editor - but most of the time WordPress is going to mess it all up for you by embedding your code in `<p>` tags after every two consecutive newline characters. This leaves the above two options that work in a reliable way without too much hassle.

#### Creating a custom template

I would recommend this if you're going to reuse this select component on multiple pages. Read up on [custom WordPress page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) in the WP docs, these are quite powerful and flexible. Here is the trick in a nutshell:

- Clone your default page template in your theme (create a child theme first if you didn't already)
- Include `Template Name: Your Template Name` in a comment at the top of the file, change the name
- Add all your scripts and styles to the template
- Create your page and set the template to your newly created template
- Enjoy your new page with superpowers that doesn't pollute the rest of the site with random JS and CSS libraries!

#### Embed in the page content itself

This is a dirty fix to the problem, but it does work, so it's up to you to decide how clean your solution needs to be. The trick is to either get a plugin that comes with a `[raw]` shortcode, or create your own. Here is a quick snippet to add such a shortcode, courtesy of [wprecipies](http://www.wprecipes.com/disable-wordpress-automatic-formatting-on-posts-using-a-shortcode)

```
function my_formatter($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'my_formatter', 99);
```

Add the above code to your theme's functions.php file. You can then add any HTML, JS and CSS inside the page content as long as you enclose it within the 'shortcode', like so:

```
[raw]
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('Im in ur contuntz, running ur skriptz!');
</script>
[/raw]
```

So for your example, you would take the code from your first link, include it all inside the content enclosed in `[raw]` tags in the order specified by the article, and boom, it would work. Hope this helps!

*Disclaimer: as mentioned above, this is a fairly hacky solution with scripts and styles inside your `<body>` tag. If you feel uncomfortable with that or want to conform to the best practices on the web, you would need to create a completely custom theme where you have control over which libraries you include on every page, and which scripts run on every page, but I believe that is outside the scope of this question.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. 

I've gone the easy route and want to embed stuff inside the page so I added that hacky function into my functions.php file (it's a child theme).

Comment: I've also added all of the code from my first link inside [raw] [/raw] and still nothing.

Your test script which returns "Im in ur contuntz, running ur skriptz!" works fine. I've put the .js files inside both the website root and also the child theme folder. 

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Check your browser's debugger if it's able to find the scripts. You need to supply the full absolute url to the `src` attribute of your tags as relative paths are hell in WP. If you placed the files inside your theme, it should look something like `http://your-domain.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/script-name.js`